# Spring Boot - Add Next and Prev links to controller response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, pageable

I have a simple controller in Spring Boot application

```
@GetMapping("/")
public Page<StockDto> listStocks(Pageable pageable) {
    return stockService.list(pageable);
}
```

It calls `list` method in `StockService` to get a list of items from the database. StockRepository is a class that extends JpaRepository with a `@Repository` annotation.

```
@Service
public class StockService {

    private StockRepository stockRepository;
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public StockService(StockRepository stockRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.stockRepository = stockRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    public Page<StockDto> list(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<StockEntity> stockEntities = stockRepository.findAll(pageable);

        return stockEntities.map(stockEntity -> modelMapper.map(stockEntity, StockDto.class));
    }
}
```

The JSON result of calling API has `content`, `pageable`, and some other fields.

I didn't use `Spring Data Rest` too. Now I want to add two Next and Prev strings that have next and previous links of getting resource in response JSON.

Comment: What you need is [Spring HATEOAS](https://spring.io/projects/spring-hateoas)

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/hateoas/pagination-links/